# composer require --dev drupal/devel isn't working

Tags: installation, composer

I followed the instructions on [prkos.hr/Install-Drupal-8-Ubuntu-1404-LTS](https://prkos.hr/Install-Drupal-8-Ubuntu-1404-LTS) for installing Drupal 8 and tried to install 'devel module' but had the error

> composer require --dev drupal/devel
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Could not find a matching version of package drupal/devel. Check the
> package spelling, your version constraint and that the  package is
> available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability
> (stable).
>
> require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed]
> [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts]
> [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies]
> [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
> [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages]
> [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
> [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...

Also I tried with the same result (from [www.drupal.org/project/devel/releases](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel/releases))

- `composer require --dev drupal/devel 2.x-dev`
- `composer require 'drupal/devel:2.x-dev'`
- `composer require 'drupal/devel:^2.0'`
- `composer require 'drupal/devel:^2.1'`

and

- `composer require drupal/devel:~1.0`

Additional info:

- `Composer version 1.10.8 2020-06-24 21:23:30`
- access right for folder and all sub-folders `drwxrwxrwx` (`chmod 777 ./ -R`)

Comment: Do you have the Drupal packagist repo in composer.json?

Comment: I don't know. How I can check this? I had no problems with command `composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev d8 --stability dev --no-interaction`

Comment: And comman `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project name_folder`working correctly

Comment: You should use `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project name_folder` as that's the currently recommended way to install. Where are you running your `composer require --dev drupal/devel` command from? Is it from just inside the *name_folder* directory from the *composer create-project* command?